# Remove Gem from RVM Gemset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec, rvm

New to RVM and playing with Rails 3 & Ruby 1.9.2 betas...

I've got two copies of rspec in a gemset. Was using beta.19 but need to downgrade to beta.18. changed my gemfile and then `bundle install`. now i have a mess...

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
. . .
rspec (2.0.0.beta.19, 2.0.0.beta.18)
rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.19, 2.0.0.beta.18)
rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.19, 2.0.0.beta.18)
rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.19, 2.0.0.beta.18)
rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.19, 2.0.0.beta.18)
```

and I would like to remove all traces of beta.19 but can't seem to find out how.

Though the Gemfile is requiring beta.18, beta.19 is still running interference...and rspec is barfing all over my log files...

**Edit**: Thanks to Nikita I was able to remove the beta.19 gems. now i'm getting a broken path or something:

```
thismac:rails_app meltemi$ spec -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable spec for rspec-2.0.0.beta.18 (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/bin/spec:19
mymac:appname meltemi$
```

is there something i need to do to rebuild now that 19 is gone and i'm falling back to 18?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about `gem uninstall rspec -v=2.0.0.beta.19` ?  Check `gem help uninstall` for details.

Or you can just uninstall all versions and then install the one you need.

Comment: thanks. got the gems "removed" but that only leads to another problem. *see above*

Comment: @Meltemi Never worked with rspec myself, but there're loads of similar reports in google:  http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=ruby+spec+`bin_path':+can't+find+executable+spec+for+rspec++(Gem::Exception)&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: thanks for your help. i was able to figure it out. my fault...probably...but not sure what i did...but it seems to be working now. confusing stuff...

Comment: http://www.basictrading.biz/2011/06/solved-rails-uninstall-gem-rake-0-9-2-from-rvm/ this might also help

Answer (score 9):

I had some similar issues with RVM due to the global and default gemsets. In my case the offending gems were in the @global gemsets and i was only able to remove them by doing

```
rvm @global do gem uninstall the-gem-name
```

Other commands like `rvm all-gemsets do...` and `rvm all do...` did not work

See this thread

[How do I use RVM and create globally available gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007171/how-do-i-use-rvm-and-create-globally-available-gems)

and the doc

http://rvm.io/set/do

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but what I needed to do was add the rspec rails to my :development group as well as :test, YMMV