# Installing MYSQL and passenger gems, getting no definitions for documentation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, macports

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6.4 and setting up rails for the first time.  I've been following a bunch of guides to get set up, specifically these two [here](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2010/02/08/installing-ruby-on-rails-passenger-postgresql-mysql-oh-my-zsh-on-snow-leopard-fourth-edition/) and [here](http://spyrestudios.com/setting-up-a-rails-development-system-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard/).  Also, I know this question has been asked before, but nothing has helped me and my circumstances are a bit different.

First, let me give you my setup.

1. I've installed Xcode, but I don't want to use the system ruby so, what I did was, I installed RVM and created two gemsets for different ruby versions (1.8.7@rails2.3.8 and 1.9.2@rails3), cause I also want to try rails 3.
2. I [created a global gemset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007171/rvm-and-global-gems) so that I could install passenger and mysql for 1.8.7 and not have to do it for each project. Then set the global gemset by `rvm gemset use global`
3. I had already installed MacPorts in a previous step, so what I've done is install mysql using this command `sudo port install mysql5 mysql5-server`.
4. Now I run `gem install passenger` and then `passenger-install-apache2-module`.  **This is where I ran into the first issue.** Passenger installed fine, but I got "no definition" errors when it tried to install the documentation.
5. Finally, I want to install the mysql gem so I followed the steps [here](http://everydayrails.com/2010/06/28/rvm-gemsets-rails3.html) by adding `rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"` to the ~/.rvmc file and then ran `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ;  gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config` **Here is where I ran into the issue again.**  I got a "Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1" message, but all the documentation returned "no definition" errors!

So, why am I getting these errors when installing gems? What can I do to get them installed without errors and ensure future gem installations don't have this problem?

**Note:** I'm not using sudo because [RVM tells you not to](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/).

Comment: no definition errors are sometimes not errors, it just means that the gem creator filed to provide documentation. Usually for new gems

Comment: Is the problem the no definition output, or is the problem that you cannot get mysql/passanger or whatever going?

Comment: no, mysql and passenger are working, as far as my tests have gone (im still new but i was able to create a rails testapp and deploy it with passenger, and i was able to create tables in mysql from terminal)

Comment: yeah, so you don't have any errors. Those no definitions just mean that there is no documentation. Stop being so careful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to your problem. They are saying the same thing and the answer is that it's just noise. Obviously something is not right but there is not and should not be a problem. It's most likely that all is fine and documentation was not created, installed, or linked correctly.

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=629077

Comment: haha thanks!  Well, its just discomforting to see errors, even if everything is working fine.  I would like to get to the bottom of why its happening, but its probably not worth the time or effort if it doesn't hinder development...

Answer (score 0):

A `--` alone (as written in step 5) usually means to stop reading options. I expect that this is wrong and doesn't belong here or is incomplete (ie, should be --*something*).