# how do you install gems that will be available to all installed rubies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Like rake for example. I don't want to have to install rake on all of my rubies.

I want to use a single installation of a gem like rake for different rubies like, ree, 1.9.2, MacRuby etc.

Comment: answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007171/how-do-i-use-rvm-and-create-globally-available-gems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [RVM docs](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/initial/):

> When installing a new ruby, RVM not only creates two gemsets (the default, empty gemset and the **global gemset**), it also uses a set of user-editable files to determine which gems to install.

You need to use the "global" gemset defined by rvm. This lets you share gems across a given Ruby version/interpreter. You cannot share gemsets across Ruby versions/interpreters.

Also, as @stephenmurdoch pointed out, this has already been answered: [How do I use RVM and create globally available gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007171/how-do-i-use-rvm-and-create-globally-available-gems)

Comment: I see. How about the ~/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems? It seems that these gems included here will not be affected by gem uninstall.

Comment: This [blog post](http://mattdenner.github.com/2010/03/09/using-rvm-gemsets.html) might make things a little clearer. The default gemset is the one which is created by default. You can assign a named gemset to be the default by using the --default option.
Also, RVM [best practices](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices/) recommend using one gemset per application!