# Globally available Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

I have numerous gems that I use across all Rails projects, but that aren't part of the projects' Gems, for example powder for managing POW.

It would make sense to me to manage these with a global Gemfile, but I can't see any examples of this.

How should I manage global Gems that I don't want in my project gemfiles? It would be good to have a single point of install for when I set up a new machine etc.

I'm using chruby alongside ruby-install to manage my Ruby versions.

Comment: Sounds like a job for RVM.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007171/how-do-i-use-rvm-and-create-globally-available-gems

Comment: @Sam Unfortunately I'm using Chruby

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a Gemfile as usual, and place it in any folder. It does not need to be a project folder. Then you can just do:

```
bundle install --system
```

This will install the gems in the Gemfile system-wide, and will ask for the root password if you do not have access to the system folder.

> **--system**:
> Installs the gems in the bundle to the system location. This overrides any previous remembered use of --path.

You can also name your Gemfile(s), if you want to organize them in some way:

```
bundle install --system --gemfile=/path/to/my_special_gemfile
```

Comment: I do not understand question was `How should I manage global Gems that I don't want in my project gemfiles?`. How is this answer?

Comment: Thanks. How would you mange gems for different versions of Ruby? A different Gemfile for each Ruby version?

Comment: @Dolphin How is it not the answer?

Comment: @Pedr It will install gems on system but they will be in project gemfile. For example if you run Rails application all gems will be in project scope. I tough you needed to install gems on system without being in project's `Gemfile`.

Comment: @Dolphin. They aren't in the project's `Gemfile`. They are in a separate `Gemfile` sitting somewhere on your system. See my answer. Maybe now you could remove your downvote from this answer as it is correct.

Comment: @Pedr Ahhh I was under assumption that this Gemfile (global) will be in project's directory together with project Gemfile, nvm my bad.

Comment: @Pedr Yes a different Gemfile sounds like a pretty straightforward solution to me. However if the differences are not big between the Gemfiles then you might consider the `:platforms` directive which can attach a specific gem to a specific Ruby major version. See more in the Gemfile manual: http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html

Comment: @Casper. Yep. That's a lot nicer. I should probably sit down and RTFM.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to @Casper's answer:

I created a directory for my system Gem files.

I then added a dir for each version of ruby I wanted to install system gems for. I added a Gemfile to each dir and a .ruby-version file with the correct version. I can now install system gems for a ruby version using:

```
$ cd path/to/system_gems_dir/1.9.3-p484
$ bundle install --system
```

or

```
$ cd cd path/to/system_gems_dir/2.0.0-p353
$ bundle install --system
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create `GlobalGemfile` file (or whatever you name it) and than you can do.

```
bundle install --gemfile GlobalGemfile
```

Cool isn't it :)