# Ruby Rake, Jenkins gem not included

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems

We are currently moving our install of Jenkins from one server to another. Someone else set up Jenkins originally and I am running into difficulties setting it up on the new server (and they aren't here to ask about it)!

Basically it fails on this line:

`require 's3'`

I believe what it is trying to do is import the amazon sdk. I installed this by doing a

`gem install s3`

Which worked, but it still can't seem to recognise it as there and include it.

I installed ruby with RVM, and have put everything on PATH (on the server and on Jenkins)
Ruby is run through Jenkins with the rake plugin.
Maybe I configured the PATH wrongly?

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Comment: Try "gem 's3', '~> 0.3.21'" in your gem file and the run bundle install, and see if the gems appears as installed in the installed gems list

Comment: Seems I didn't have the s3 gem installed globally! this answered the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13552937/1624933